# Partition a list dependent on consecutive list values

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review, partitions

I have a list of 2D points which I partition every time the distance between consecutive list elements is bigger than a certain threshold. In a second step I select all the lists that start within a radius of 1 from the origin.

Any ideas to improve my current code?

Generate some test data:

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[Table[
     Table[a + s RotationMatrix[b].{0, 1}, {s, 0, 10, 0.1}], {b, 
      RandomReal[2 Pi, 5]}], {a, {{0, .1}, {1, 2}, {0.4, 0.2}, {1, 
       1}, {-2, 1}}}], 2];
ListPlot@Partition[data, 101]
```

[image]

Partition the data:

```
sepL = Most[0.2 > Norm[#1 - #2] & @@@ Transpose[{data, RotateLeft@data}]];
parts = Partition[Flatten@{1, 1 + Accumulate[Length@# & /@ Split[sepL]]}, 2];
res = Select[data[[#1 ;; #2]] & @@@ parts, Norm[#[[1]]] < 1 &];
ListPlot@res
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[42];
data = Flatten[Table[Table[Table[a + s RotationMatrix[b].{0, 1}, {s, 0, 10, 0.1}],
     {b, RandomReal[2 Pi, 5]}], {a, {{0, .1}, {1, 2}, {0.4, 0.2}, {1, 1}, {-2, 1}}}], 2];

res2 = Split[data, Norm[#1 - #2] < .2 &]; 
res == res2 (* res = SplitBy[data, Norm[f@# - #] < .2 &]; -- from belisarius' post *)
(* True *)

data2 = Pick[res2, Norm@First@# < 1. & /@ res2];
(* or data2 = Pick[res2, Unitize[Norm@First@res2 - 1.], 0]; *)
ListPlot[data2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like a flip-flop:

```
ClearAll[f, h];
Module[{i = True},
       h[_] := {};
       f[x_] := (h[i = ! i] = x;
                 If[# == {}, x, #] &@h[! i])
 ]
res = SplitBy[data, Norm[f@# - #] < .2 &];
ListPlot@Select[res, Norm[#[[1]]] < 1 &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @belisarius It gets slower and slower as you update it, please stop ;)

Comment: @paw Oh,sorry. I was trying to make the code easier to understand and disregarding the performance issues. You can always find the older versions at the [revision history](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/61443/revisions) of course